# 13.10 Can't see results from software center in dash

Tags: software-center, 13.10, unity-dash

In 13.04 everything was ok but in 13.10 I don't see results from Software Center. I would like to install some apps using Dash but whatever I type I get no results (I select software center in sources section in applications scope), and I have online sources enabled.

Is there any fix for this

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the  `unity-scopes-master-default` package is installed

Comment: It's already installed